# MSBuild: How can I check are the files existing?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, msbuild

MS Visual Studio 2012; MSBuild.

I am getting an error (error MSB4184) if the files ain't exist. I am trying to set a condition, but it is ending in invalid syntax... Please find below code from my proj-file:

```
<Target Name="Resources">
    <GenerateResource Condition = " $([System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles(&quot;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\resources&quot;,&quot;*.*&quot;, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)::Length) != 0 "
        Sources="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\resources\**\*.*">
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputResources"
            ItemName="Resources"/>
    </GenerateResource>
</Target>
```

This condition is like the:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\resources","*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check this with the `Condition` and an `ItemGroup` declaration as below:

```
<Target Name="Resources">
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\resources\**\*.*;"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <GenerateResource Condition="Exists('%(PackageFiles.FullPath)')" Sources="@(PackageFiles)">
        <Output TaskParameter="OutputResources" ItemName="Resources"/>
    </GenerateResource>
</Target>
```

Probably you may need some customizations in the `Output` tag as per your requirement.